# Can we merge handlebars js with angular 4?

Tags: angular, handlebars.js

Can we merge handlebars js with angular 4? Can we build an app using these 2 frameworks? And what types of projects can we build using handlebars js like e-commerce, banking, CMS etc. projects?

Comment: Please ask only one question by post with more specific details. See this for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can merge handlebars.js with Angular.  The main issue would be setting up routing.  Angular is designed to be a single-page application (SPA) and would catch all routes unless specifically escaped, which can be done using your own custom backend (eg. Node.js).  You can then connect this escaped route for the specific `.handlebars` webpage.

Here is a general `server.js` file that does this using NodeJS, Express, and express-handlebars:

```
// Dependencies
const express = require('express');
const exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');

// Configuration
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Routes
const angular = require('./node_src/routes/angular');
const api = require('./node_src/routes/api');

// View engine
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

// Angular Route
const angularBuildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '/dist');
app.use(express.static(angularBuildPath));
app.get('*', function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.url.startsWith('/my-handlebars-page')) return next();   // ESCAPED ROUTE
    res.sendFile(path.join(angularBuildPath, 'index.html'))
});

// ESCAPED ROUTE
app.get('/my-handlebars-page', function (req, res) {
    res.render('home');
});

// Start Server
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));
```